# game score increasing by time when start button is pressed

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit

Im having a hard time getting the game score to increase by time rather than game events.  The score is an SKlabelnode that is displayed when the game is started.  I want the score to increase as game time goes on, and then restart back at 0 when the game is restarted (ie: the player dies)

The score label stays at 0, ive tried numerous variations of code

```
//score
   var score = Int()
   var highScore = Int()
   let scoreLable = SKLabelNode()





    scoreLable.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 1.1, y: self.frame.height / 1.1)
    scoreLable.zPosition = 5
    scoreLable.fontSize = 100
    scoreLable.fontName = "AppleSDGothicNeo-bold"
    scoreLable.text = "\(score)"




func ScoreAndHighScore(){
   score = score+1
   }

var scoreTimer = Timer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ScoreAndHighScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the label's text every time the score value is increased.

```
func ScoreAndHighScore() {
    score += 1
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
}
```

Comment: @TroyDeJ - Have you actually invoked the timer? Try setting a breakpoint inside the `ScoreAndHighScore` method to make sure it's even being called. If it's not, try using `scheduledTimer` like call `Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ScoreAndHighScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` in `viewDidLoad` just to test

Comment: just tried both and neither works, makes me think the code is just completely wrong.

Comment: @TroyDeJ - Can you post some more of your code? Have you actually added the label to your scene? `addChild(scoreLabel)`?. Another thing I would recommend is updating the label text in the `update(currentTime:)`

Comment: got it! had to use `var scoreTime = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ScoreAndHighScore), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: Awesome. Yeah you always want to make sure you actually schedule the timer. When you first instantiate the timer, it doesn't necessarily fire it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using SKActions as your timers rather than an NSTimer. You could do something like this:

```
let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
let incrementScoreAction = SKAction.run {
   //code to increment score
}

let repeatIncrementScore = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, incrementScoreAction]))

self.run(repeatIncrementScore)
```

Comment: how would i do the same thing with skactions?

Comment: just tried it, works great and a much better way. thank you immensely

Comment: @TroyDeJ, Glad it worked out for you. Would  you mind accepting the answer?